# How to iterating string in df using python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have data

```
                     date                    id           request 
0     2016-06-17 09:25:05  yans.bouts@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1   
1     2016-06-17 09:25:07  yans.bouts@yandex.ru     POST HTTP/1.1   
2     2016-06-17 09:25:47  yans.bouts@yandex.ru  CONNECT HTTP/1.1   
3     2016-06-17 09:25:47  yans.bouts@yandex.ru     POST HTTP/1.1   
4     2016-06-17 09:25:49  yans.bouts@yandex.ru  CONNECT HTTP/1.1
```

I need to iterate string and  `'GET' not in df['request']` I want to delete string from df.

Desire output

```
               date                    id           request 
0     2016-06-17 09:25:05  yans.bouts@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1
```

I try `df = df['GET' in df.request]` but it returns

> KeyError: False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `mask` created by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print (df.request.str.contains('GET'))
0  2016-06-17     True
1  2016-06-17    False
2  2016-06-17    False
3  2016-06-17    False
4  2016-06-17    False

print (df[df.request.str.contains('GET')])
                  date                    id       request
0 2016-06-17  09:25:05  yans.bouts@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1
```

EDIT by comment:

For comparing column `size` use `[]`, because [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) is function:

```
df_upd = df_upd[df_upd['size'].astype(int) > 3000]
```

Comment: Can you say, why `df_upd = df_upd[int(df_upd.size) > 3000]` return `keyerror`? I also need to compare size(I have this column), and if it less that 3000, delete that string

Comment: You need [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) for casting to `int`  - `df_upd = df_upd[df_upd.size.astype(int) > 3000]`

Comment: it also return `KeyError: True`

Comment: Hmmmm, there is another problem - [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.size.html) is function. So you need `[]` - `df_upd = df_upd[df_upd['size'].astype(int) > 3000]`

Comment: btw, I  have similar issues  very often, because I like column names with same names as function like `count`, `size`...

Comment: yes, if use `[]` it is more safer, but with `.` it is nicer ;)